# Prove that $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$X=C[0,1]$

(i) Prove that if the sequence $(f_n)_{n\ge1} \subseteq X$ converges to $f \in X$ in the supremum norm, then for each $t\in[0,1]$ one necessarily has $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t) = f(t)$.

(ii) Let $V \subseteq X$ be the following linear subspace: $V =\{f \in X\mid f(0) = f(1) = 0\}$. Using (I), or otherwise, prove that $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ is a Banach space. You may use results from the course without proof.

---

(i) Since sequence $(f_n)_{n\ge1} \subseteq X$ converges to $f \in X$, then $\forall \varepsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $\lVert f_n (t)-f(t)\rVert_{\infty} = \sup |f_n (t)-f(t)|< \varepsilon $ whenever $n>N$. True for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Notice $|f_n(t)-f(t)|\le\lVert f_n (t)-f(t)\rVert_{\infty} = \sup |f_n (t)-f(t)|< \varepsilon $ whenever $n>N$. So $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t) = f(t)$.

(ii) I am not sure with this one but I feel that the result I have to use is that $(V,\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ is a Banach space $\iff$ $V$ is a closed subset of $X$ but then this wouldn't be using the previous part of the question...

Please help and is my (i) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) is correct.

(ii) Show that $\{ f \in X : f(0)=0\}$ and $\{ f \in X : f(1)=0\}$  are closed subspaces of $X$: from this, you will have that $V$ is an intersection of closed sets, hence closed. This can be done using sequences, and (i).
Pick a sequence $f_n \subset \{ f \in X : f(0)=0\}$ converging to some $f$ in $X$.
But (i) shows that $$f(0) = \lim_n f_n(0) = \lim_n 0=0$$ so that $f \in \{ f \in X : f(0)=0\}$. This proves that $\{ f \in X : f(0)=0\}$ is closed. SImilarly you can prove the other one.

Comment: So we have to show that X\V is open?

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: So $f(1)=\lim f_n(1) = \lim 0 =0$ so $f \{f \in X : f(1)=0 \}$? So then it is closed. I had no idea that showing this makes it "closed". I always thought closed meant like open and closed sets.

Comment: Could you explain how this shows it is closed... I don't understand why. Also we didn't consider $t \in (0,1)$

Comment: See Theorem 4.12 in [these notes](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~mj/MTH6126/note4.pdf)